# Cannot declare Char type variable

Tags: vba, char, declare

Visual Basic does not recognize the Char type. The closest match in hints to char is characters.

I searched some forums and guides but found nothing

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: VBA/VB6 does not have a Char type (VB.Net *does*). There is Byte (0..255) or String, which is appropriate depends on what you want to do .,.

Comment: Char is a C declaration.  In VBA you want a type of String.

Comment: I want to get some letters from a string so i followed this site https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233783.aspx but the char or chars just dont work for me .

And many thanks for the ultra-fast response :)

Comment: The link is about vb.net therefor it's not working. VBA does not have char see here [the data types in VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263420%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

Comment: Character #3 in VBA is `x = mid$(thestring, 3, 1)` ([ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251677.aspx))

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
Dim myString As String * 1
```

This works for any length.